# How is a tuple immutable if you can add to it (a += (3,4))

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
>>> a = (1,2)
>>> a += (3,4)
>>> a
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>>
```

and with a list:

```
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> b += [3,4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

As a tuple is immutable and list is mutable, how can we explain the behaviour?

Comment: I think `+=` defines a new tuple and returns it (i.e. doesn't mutate an existing one). The key is not the values you are seeing, but whether the underlying object is the same. With lists, the same object is added onto (a new one is not created).

Comment: Numbers are also immutable, but `a = 2; a += 2` works.

Comment: @cool_n_curious be warned though, this is a costly operation for tuples. Lists can simply extend themselves while tuples have to contruct a completely new tuple each time you do this, so use lists whenever you need to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuple is of immutable type, means that you cannot change the values stored in the variable `a`. For example, doing the following

```
>>> a = (1, 2)
>>> a[0] = 3
```

throws up the error `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`.

On the other hand, for a list,

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> a[0] = 3
```

this is perfectly valid because it is mutable.

What you are doing is reassigning values to the variable names.

`a = a + (3, 4)` which just concatenates the two and reassigns it to the variable `a`. You are not actually changing the value of the tuple.

For example, `string` is immutable, and hence,

```
>>> name = "Foo"
>>> name[0] ='o'
```

throws up a similar error as above. But, the following is a reassignment and completely valid.

```
>>> name = name + " Bar"
>>> name
'Foo Bar'
```

and it just does a concatenation.

Answer (score 10):

In the example, you're not changing the actual tuple, you're only changing the tuple that the variable `a` is pointing to. In this example `a += (3, 4)` is the same as `a = a + (3, 4)`. If we check the `id` of `a` before and after the operation, we can see the difference:

```
>>> a = (1, 2)
>>> id(a)
60516360
>>> a += (3, 4)
>>> id(a)
61179528
```

With lists, `+=` calls `.extend()` on the list, which changes it in-place.

```
>>> b = [1, 2]
>>> id(b)
62480328
>>> b += [3, 4]
>>> id(b)
62480328
```

Notice that the `id` of `b` doesn't change after the operation.